# UITableView height change when scrolling with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I took UIViewController which have 2 UITableView.
How to use the method **`scrollViewDidloadScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`** to do stretches to the Top Layout Guide?
Project on Objective C.

[image]

Comment: Provide more information and retype your question, it's not understable for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it using tags. Need assign tag to tableview object,

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
//Need to give tag value to table view
if(scrollView.tag == 100){
    //table1
}else if(scrollView.tag == 101){
    //table2
}}
```

Hope this will hep you